# issue with static image loading using nginx to proxy pass a nuxt application which is located in a different server

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, nginx, nuxt.js

We have a CMS system in our main website e.g. example.com in ServerA. We want to run a Nuxtjs (version 2) application running in a different EC2 server (ServerB). We want to run the Nuxt application in the subdirectory of example.com like example.com/web

We are using Nginx as a reverse proxy. We can use the proxy_pass directive to route the /web requests to our Nuxt application. But the problem is that the Nuxt application cannot load the static files. Though the Nuxt application is running on ServerB, it's trying to load the static resources from ServerA like this http://ServerA_ip_address/_nuxt/assets/cute-dog.jpg when using the proxy_pass.

It should load the static resources like this http://ServerB_ip_address/_nuxt/assets/cute-dog.jpg

Both servers are running on AWS EC2 Ubuntu instances. I haven't changed anything in the Nuxtjs config file.

This is my nginx configuration in ServerA.

```
server {
  # Port listen
  listen 80;

  # DNS Record for catch request
  server_name ServerB_ip_address;


  # Open block for process forward request
  location /app/ {
    # Server where traffic is transferred
    proxy_pass http://ServerB_ip_address/;
  }
}
```

I want to able to run my Nuxt application in example.com/web
Thanks in advance everyone.